# How to get the profit from CTrade after trade.sell?

Tags: c++, mql5, metatrader5

I cannot get the value of a trade profit in `MQL5` in `metatrader5`, because it always returns 0.0 :

```
 MqlTradeCheckResult result;
 trade.CheckResult(result);
 Print("result balance=" + result.balance);
```

Or another attempt :

```
 double tradeResultProfit = trade.CheckResultProfit();
 Print("trade Profit = ", tradeResultProfit);
 double tradeResultBalance = trade.CheckResultBalance();
 Print("trade Balance = ", tradeResultBalance);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been informed that this is a bug in MQL5
A workaround is to play with the account balance before the trade ane the balance after the trade...